# In Symfony2, how can can I customize a routing.xml url from parameters.yml

Tags: symfony

I have 3 domains setup: mydomain.com, mydomain-staging.com and mydomain-dev.com

I am using an angularJS app to register new users, which sends the registration details to FOSUserBundle (I am using a Symfony2 RESTful api).

Everything is working apart from the confirmation link in the email, which FOSUserBundle is setting to (for example) http://api.mydomain-staging.com/register/confirm/[token]. I think it is setting the subdomain to api as that is where the request came from.

I'm trying to edit registration.xml so I can set the routes for the registration urls to always be for the website subdomain "admin" instead "api" e.g. http://admin.mydomain-staging.com/register/confirm/[token]

I want to put the actual domain into parameters.yml as that file is created on each server. Then refer to the parameter in the xml.

This is my latest attempt, but it gives me the url http://admin.mydomain.com/register/confirm/[token] on all 3 servers, instead of taking the domain from paramters.yml

MyUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml

```
...
<route id="fos_user_registration_confirm" pattern="/confirm/{token}" host="admin.{_domain}">
    <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Registration:confirm</default>
    <requirement key="_method">GET</requirement>
    <requirement key="_domain">%app.domain%</requirement>
    <default key="_domain">mydomain.com</default>
</route>
...
```

app/config/config.yml

```
...
parameters:
    app.domain: "%app_domain%"
...
```

app/config/paramters.yml

```
...
app_domain: mydomain-staging.com
...
```

edit:
I've tried using the environment config files as well (e.g. config_staging.yml), but routing.xml keeps using the

```
<default key="_domain">...</default>
```

value instead of going to my config file.

If I remove the default from the xml I get an error: Some mandatory parameters are missing (\"_domain\") to generate a URL for route \"fos_user_registration_confirm\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the xml I was using. I should have had the variable in the default, not the requirement. Like this:

```
<route id="fos_user_registration_confirm" pattern="/confirm/{token}" host="admin.{_domain}">
    <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Registration:confirm</default>
    <requirement key="_method">GET</requirement>
    <default key="_domain">%app.domain%</default>
</route>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that by creating 3 environments with 3 front controllers(`web/app.php`, `web/app_dev.php`, `web/app_stage.php`) with 3 config files (`config.yml`, `config_dev.yml` and `config_stage.yml`) in the config files overwrite the parameter `app_domain` as suited for your servers.
see [Symfony Environments](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html) for more details.